# PHP code not executed after system() command when trying to print realtime output of command

Tags: php, exec

I have this code to run command and print realtime output, the problem is that the code after `system()` command doesn´t get executed. How can I fix this problem?

```
function disable_ob() {
        // Turn off output buffering
        ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
        // Turn off PHP output compression
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);
        // Implicitly flush the buffer(s)
        ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
        ob_implicit_flush(true);
        // Clear, and turn off output buffering
        while (ob_get_level() > 0) {
            // Get the curent level
            $level = ob_get_level();
            // End the buffering
            ob_end_clean();
            // If the current level has not changed, abort
            if (ob_get_level() == $level) break;
        }
        // Disable apache output buffering/compression
        if (function_exists('apache_setenv')) {
            apache_setenv('no-gzip', '1');
            apache_setenv('dont-vary', '1');
        }
    }

function build() {
        $location = "build/" . date("Y-m-d-h-i-sa");

        echo "Build started! Your build location is " . $location;
        $url =  "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}";
        $escaped_url = htmlspecialchars( $url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );       
        echo "\nIf you don´t get redirected after build go to $escaped_url/" . $location . "/smefs-Indigo-Remastered-master/Release/smef.pw.dll\n";
        echo "...\n";

        mkdir($location, 0777, true);
        dircpy("","buildfiles/smefs-Indigo-Remastered-master",$location . "/smefs-Indigo-Remastered-master",true);
        copy("buildfiles/buildscript.bat",$location . "/buildscript.bat");
        copy("buildfiles/JunkCode.exe",$location . "/JunkCode.exe");
        #shell_exec('call ' . $location . "/buildscript.bat");

        system('call ' . $location . "/buildscript.bat");

        # THIS CODE NOT EXECUTED
        echo "\n\n# BUILD COMPLETED #";
        echo "If you aren´t redirected please go to this link to download build: " . $location . "/smefs-Indigo-Remastered-master/Release/smef.pw.dll";
        header('Location: '. $location . "/smefs-Indigo-Remastered-master/Release/smef.pw.dll");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! The problem was, that I had timeout set to 30 seconds. After adding `ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);` everything works!